# Docker run does not display any output

Tags: docker, ssh, raspberry-pi

I installed docker on a raspberry-pi (Connected via ssh)
Installation is successful.

But running `docker run hello-world` produce no output.

Note on very first time I got additional messages regard installing image

`Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
ad0f38092cf2: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:e366bc07db5e8a50dbabadd94c2a95d212bc103e3557e47df8a2eebd8bb46309
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest`

But there is no actual output from hello world script

Note I installed docker using command `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh`

I tried following command too

```
sudo usermod -aG docker pi
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo docker run hello-world
```

Tried following commands     docker ps -a

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS                           PORTS               NAMES
734dd8f733d7        hello-world         "/hello"            About a minute ago   Exited (139) 59 seconds ago                          thirsty_bhaskara
```

Answer (score 26):

I ran into the same issue on a Raspberry Pi 1B+ (armv6l). Inspired by @JanDrábek's answer, the first observation is that the `hello-world` image would indeed be one supporting ARM, yet only after using `hypriot/armhf-hello-world` instead did I get the expected output:

```
$ uname -a
Linux 4.1.19+ #858 Tue Mar 15 15:52:03 GMT 2016 armv6l GNU/Linux
$ docker run hello-world  # No output
$ docker image inspect hello-world | grep Architecture  # Arch looks right though
        "Architecture": "arm",
$ docker run hypriot/armhf-hello-world  # This does the job
Hello from Docker.
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
```

Comment: Any idea why 'hypriot/armhf-hello-world' works and the standard one does not?

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: I am using Raspberry Pi 2. Docker seems to work fine with regular hello-world, but podman is giving no output. Podman works only with `hypriot/armhf-hello-world`

Answer (score 25):

run:

```
docker ps -a
```

and check if you can see the exited container.

take the container ID from the output and type

```
docker logs <ID>
```

this will allow you to see the logs.

if you want to see the output in the first place when you run it add `-it` flags to the run command

edit:

I tried in on my machine:

```
docker run -it hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
d1725b59e92d: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:e366bc07db5e8a50dbabadd94c2a95d212bc103e3557e47df8a2eebd8bb46309
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
```

maybe your output is redirected to some other stream.
try using :

```
docker run -it hello-world > ./test.txt 2>&1
```

after that check if the file has any content

Comment: Tried ` docker run -it hello-world; docker logs 734dd8f733d7`  no output

Comment: Was getting no output running normally and no logs. Using the '-it' flag made it work thanks.

Comment: I was missing the -it. didn't think that was necessary for the docker logs to show the logs.

Answer (score 7):

I was having similar issue, my solution was definitely very naive but I basically removed all container and images and then tried again. It worked.

```sh
# Delete all containers
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
# Delete all images
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

Comment: Just a note that people should take _great care_ before doing this!

Answer (score 2):

I recently had same problem on my freshly installed Fedora 28 (up-to-date)... the containers all exited with exit code 139, the `docker events` said that it died, and `docker logs` said nothing.

My solution was to update the docker (or switch to CE edition) as the installed docker version was 1.13 which is quite old. (The tutorial for fedora https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/fedora/)

Also I have came across one potential thing to check... is your container compatible with your architecture (raspberry is ARM isn't it?) Use `docker image inspect <image>` search for `Architecture`.